# Generating random numbers with ARM Assembly

Tags: objective-c, arm, random, inline-assembly

I want to generate random number to use it in my iphone project by Inlining in my Objective-C code some assembly, is this possible with arm-assembly?

Comment: What's wrong with the stdlib generator - no need for assembly there.

Comment: Yes but just the objective of exercice is to do it with arm assembly ..

Comment: Do you want to write a random number generator in assembly from scratch, or what, because that would be long and difficult road methinks.

Comment: Is there a need that generator every call returns *new* random number? If not, simply roll a dice and then write MOV Rx, <value_from_dice>. Guaranteed random.

Answer (score 1):

Look up lfsr on google, linear feedback shift register.  Not a true random number generator but you can make pretty good random numbers with maybe three or four lines of assembler.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Wikipedia, find the easiest random number generation algorithm, reimplement in assembly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
; ========================= RANDOM.INC =========================
; Call with,    NOTHING

; Returns,  AL = random number between 0-255,
;       AX may be a random number too ?
;       DW RNDNUM holds AX=random_number_in AL
SEED    DW 3749h
RNDNUM  DW 0
align 16
RANDOM:
PUSH    DX
MOV AX,[SEED]   ;; AX = seed
MOV DX,8405h    ;; DX = 8405h
MUL DX      ;; MUL (8405h * SEED) into dword DX:AX
;
CMP AX,[SEED]
JNZ GOTSEED     ;; if new SEED = old SEED, alter SEED
MOV AH,DL
INC AX
GOTSEED:
MOV WORD [SEED],AX  ;; We have a new seed, so store it
MOV AX,DX       ;; AL = random number
MOV WORD [RNDNUM],AX
POP DX
RET
```

Comment: Can you please provide a little more explanation? I am an assembly learner and very newbie about this. Thank you already.

Comment: This is 16-bit x86 assembly, not ARM.  The same simplistic PRNG (LCG with a fixed starting seed) could be implemented for ARM if you wanted...

Answer (score -2):

Jost load a variable from an uninitialized memory address. At every access, increment address to get new random numbers. Voila, guarenteed random, but not well distributed.

Comment: Also, will crash the program eventually (if not right away). There's memory protection on ARM, y'know.

Comment: If you stay in your application's memory you won't have problems with that.

Comment: still no guarantee, you may hit an unallocated address or an execute-only, no-read page. Or a guard page.